# Google Compute Engine image metadata blank

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I query the metadata server on an instance like this:

```
curl "http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/?recursive=true&alt=text" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

All the metadata is returned but the **image** metadata value is blank.  As far as I can tell this should be the name of the image the instance was created from.

I tried instances made from two different images in the list. centos-6 and debian-7 but on both instances the image parameter is blank.

I created both of these in us-central-1b.

Am I misunderstanding what this parameter is for?  When should I expect to see the image parameter have a value that is not blank?

Comment: To Followup I was able to file a ticket with Google and they were able to reproduce this bug.  They are working on it.

Comment: Do you have a case # ?

Comment: I don't it was kind of a back channel way of reporting the bug.    However I got this reply back yesterday that is not quite the response I was hoping for:   ((Apparently the "image" value in the metadata server has been blank for over a year now, and will remain that way for the foreseeable future.  ))   bummer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should mark this as answered.  The bug is not fixed as of yet but Google as acknowledged it and is working on it.